# Show z-value at mouse pointer position in status line with matplotlib's pcolormesh()

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using `imshow()` the z-value of the mouse pointer is shown in the status line as shown in the screen shot (on the right):
[image: screenshot imshow and pcolormesh]
How do I achieve the same behavior with `pcolormesh()`?

The image was generated by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(t, 2*t)
Z = np.sin(2*np.pi*(X**2+Y**2))
fig, axx = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axx[0].set_title("imshow()")
axx[0].imshow(Z, origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=[-1, 1, -2, 2])
axx[1].set_title("pcolormesh()")
axx[1].pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea is to monkey patch the `ax.format_coord` function to include the desired value. This is also shown in [a matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_zcoord.html).

### Specific solution

Now if you want both plots share the same function, a little bit of work needs to be spent on getting the axes limits correct.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(t, 2*t)
Z = np.sin(np.pi*(X**2+Y**2))


fig, axx = plt.subplots(1, 2)

axx[0].set_title("imshow()")
extent = [-1-(t[1]-t[0])/2., 1+(t[1]-t[0])/2., -2-(t[1]-t[0]), 2+(t[1]-t[0])]
axx[0].imshow(Z, origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=extent)

axx[1].set_title("pcolormesh()")
axx[1].pcolormesh(X-(t[1]-t[0])/2., Y-(t[1]-t[0]), Z)
axx[1].set_xlim(-1-(t[1]-t[0])/2., 1+(t[1]-t[0])/2.)
axx[1].set_ylim( -2-(t[1]-t[0]), 2+(t[1]-t[0]) )

def format_coord(x, y):
    x0, x1 = axx[1].get_xlim()
    y0, y1 = axx[1].get_ylim()
    col = int(np.floor((x-x0)/float(x1-x0)*X.shape[1]))
    row = int(np.floor((y-y0)/float(y1-y0)*Y.shape[0]))
    if col >= 0 and col < Z.shape[1] and row >= 0 and row < Z.shape[0]:
        z = Z[row, col]
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f, z=%1.4f' % (x, y, z)
    else:
        return 'x=%1.4f, y=%1.4f' % (x, y)

axx[1].format_coord = format_coord


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### General solution

The above is specific to the data in the question and has the drawback of not allowing to zoom and pan in the plot. A completely general solution would need to take into account the possibility that the image does not fill the complete axes and also the fact that pcolormesh pixels may be of unequal sizes.

This could look as follows, where in addition, the pixel numbers are shown:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-3, -2, 0, 1.5, 2.2, 3.2, 3.9, 5, 6.75, 9]
y = [7, 7.1, 7.5, 7.7, 8, 8.2, 8.4, 8.8, 9]

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=np.array(X.shape)-1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pc = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
fig.colorbar(pc)

def format_coord(x, y):
    xarr = X[0,:]
    yarr = Y[:,0]
    if ((x > xarr.min()) & (x <= xarr.max()) & 
        (y > yarr.min()) & (y <= yarr.max())):
        col = np.searchsorted(xarr, x)-1
        row = np.searchsorted(yarr, y)-1
        z = Z[row, col]
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}, z={z:1.4f}   [{row},{col}]'
    else:
        return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}'

ax.format_coord = format_coord

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As far as I see it, the solution does not work properly, if the canvas / plot was zoomed, or am I wrong?

Comment: @user7468395 If the canvas is resized, this will stay correct, but you are right that if the axes is zoomed, it will not work anymore. I suppose my main focus was on showing how to do this as a proof of principle. You can use more complex code inside the function to determine the value at the position of the mouse pointer. I might update this at some point, but if you have a good solution at hand, feel free to edit the answer or provide a new one here.

Comment: @user7468395 I updated the answer with a more general solution, which allows for zooming.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I wonder is there any way to make this more general? Would it be possible to let `format_coord` take three arguments and use the thrid argument to pass `X`, `Y` and `Z`? Many thanks!

Comment: This raises a `TypeError` if one of the coordinates is a datetime. Any ideas on how we could make the above work also for datetime axes? Thanks!